# add dynamic ids using $scope variables in dynamically added html elements

Tags: html, angularjs

Please see my code below and help me correct what I'm doing wrong:

```
$scope.more_work_counter=0;
$scope.appendWork = function(){
  $scope.more_work=$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.more_work+'<input type="text" class="form-control more-work-fields" id="{{more_work_counter}}"><button class="btn btn-danger del-more-work-btn">-</button>'+'</br>');
  $scope.more_work_counter++;
}
```

Below is the image of my DOM along with IDs I want to add in the input fields:

[image: DOM Image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in your html ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but this is certainly wrong. The HTML code should be in the template. It should be generated thanks to directives (ng-repeat, etc.) and update itself based on changes in the model. The model should just be JavaScript objects and arrays.

Comment: i was trying to add html elements (input and buttons) dynamically when a certain button is pressed.  and want to assign those input and buttons some dynamic ids based on how many of them are generated

Comment: Please check my demo -  http://plnkr.co/edit/qde8rRl3sIVJGKXmfO3S?p=preview - it does exactly that

Comment: oh i see, i got your approach thanks for the help dude. @shershen (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your sample code, you may want to add more fields to display in your html. You can use ng-repeat directive, check [**this plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qde8rRl3sIVJGKXmfO3S?p=preview) I've made

controller code:

```
  $scope.fields = [
    {id: 1}
    ];

    $scope.addField = function(){
       $scope.fields.push({
         id : $scope.fields.length
       });
    }
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
  <input type="text" class="form-control more-work-fields" id="{{$index}}">
  <button class="btn btn-danger del-more-work-btn">-</button>
</div>  
<button ng-click="addField()">add field</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i guess you miss understood my question. i want to add new fields whenever user presses the "add" button so ng-repeat won't work in that matter :)

Comment: hmmm, "add new fields whenever user presses the "add" button" - that's exactly what happens in demo. however up to you

Comment: @shujaat1989 that's what this exmple does. When you click on "add field", a new field is added in the model, and since the html template iterates on the fields and generates an input and a button for each field using ng-repeat, it does exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

ok i did this and it worked... the old technique used in php so many times

```
$scope.appendWork = function(){

        $scope.more_work=$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.more_work+'<input type="text" class="form-control more-work-fields" id="'+$scope.more_work_counter+'"><button class="btn btn-danger del-more-work-btn">-</button>'+'</br>');
        $scope.more_work_counter++;

    }
```